# Identification of this species of Toad

Tags: zoology, species-identification, herpetology

I found a short video on the Internet of a toad and I wonder if anybody could identify it?

It was posted on a social-media/blogging website called 'Tumblr',

- so I don't know much about it (e.g., where the video took place).

**EDIT:** The original link is no longer active. Here's an [alternate link](https://youtu.be/YBDejUj2w3A).

- Useful for hearing the specimen's "squeak"/scream.

**EDIT 2:** Here's a gif of some frames from the video for permanence on this site:

[image]

P.s. I **think** it's a *toad*. Please, don't hesitate to correct me/edit my question, if i'm mistaken.

Comment: Do you know where the animal is from?

Comment: In all honesty, I'm not sure. Although i would Initially suspect it was filmed in North America. I presume, that the person in the video is keeping it as a pet too, so, it could be sourced far from there... Sorry, I'm not too helpful on this one :(

Comment: @p.s.w.g thanks for the update, but your link *also* doesn't seem to work :/

Comment: @theforestecologist whoops... copy/paste error. I've corrected the link (but will need to be reviewed)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This indeed looks like a species of "Pacman Frog."

Specifically, this specimen most resembles the terrestrial [***Ceratophrys cranwelli***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cranwell%27s_horned_frog) (**Cranwell's horned frog** or **Chacoan horned frog**).

[image: Chacoan Horned Frog]

<sup>© 2014 [James H. Harding](http://calphotos.berkeley.edu/cgi/img_query?enlarge=0000+0000+1014+0006)</sup>

**Facts:**

- 8-13 cm long; can weigh up to 0.5 kg.
- Origin: endemic to dry Gran Chaco region of Argentina, Bolivia, Paraguay and Brazil.
- Cranwell's are very popular as pets.
- Their common name comes from their large mouths. According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cranwell%27s_horned_frog):

  > Like most members of the genus *Ceratophrys*, they are often considered Pacman frogs because of their resemblance to the popular video game character of the same name.
- Like most reptiles/amphibians traded worldwide as pets, a fair amount of interbreeding between captive species (and even speciation as a result of captivity) result in various hybrids and color schemes.
- I couldn't find any reputable sources describing the sound the frog makes in the video, but [Valetti et al. (2013)](http://www.scielo.sa.cr/pdf/rbt/v61n1/a22v61n1.pdf) studied their calls in the wild.
- Closely related *Ceratophrys ornata* is both [larger](http://amphibiancare.com/2005/06/05/horned-frogs/) and typically much [greener](http://calphotos.berkeley.edu/imgs/512x768/0000_0000/0106/0864.jpeg) compared to *C. cranwelli*.

Answer (score 3):

It looks to me like it's a Pacman frog or Ornate Horned frog, a common pet frog. The specific species, by googling pet websites, my guess is Ceratophrys Cranwelli (common name Brown Pacman frog).

Comment: They most certainly do look very similar! I'll look into it, now. Thank you for your contribution. +1. I'll mark your post as the answer, if so.

Answer (score 1):

It is almost certainly a toad, not a frog as the name of the video suggests. It probably belongs to the familie *Pseudepidalea*, aka the green toads. The live in Europe, Asia and North-America. [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudepidalea)

I don't know the species, as I am.not familiar with the North-American species. This animal has relative large and few spots. That may help in identification, but may also be intra-species variation.

I can't see the video, only the opening still.

Comment: I apologise for the issues with the video, I'm not sure if I'm able to suggest any "work-around", for it neither. Your contribution to this question is much appreciated, however. Thank you for your time. +1